# How to save multiple summary(lm) to a file/files?

Tags: r

I would like to save multiple summary(lm) as a txt files.
I was trying below function, it works well for counter=1,2,3 however it is not working for the loop - there are empty files.

Do you have any suggestions?

```
output_folder<-c("C:/temp/")
for(counter in 1:3){ #for loop it saves empty files
#counter<-2
x<-rnorm(100,0,1)
y<-rnorm(100,0,2)

lm.model<-lm(x~y)

sink(file=paste(output_folder, "RegressionSummary_", counter,".txt", sep = ""))
summary(lm.model)
sink()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough about R's internals to say why you need to do this, but if you wrap the `summary` call with a call to `print` your code works:

```
output_folder<-c("C:/temp/")
for(counter in 1:3){ #for loop it saves empty files
#counter<-2
x<-rnorm(100,0,1)
y<-rnorm(100,0,2)

lm.model<-lm(x~y)

sink(file=paste(output_folder, "RegressionSummary_", counter,".txt", sep = ""))
print(summary(lm.model))
sink()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
output_folder<-c("C:/temp/")
summaries    <- c()
for(counter in 1:3){ #for loop it saves empty files
  #counter<-2
  x<-rnorm(100,0,1)
  y<-rnorm(100,0,2)

  lm.model.sum <-summary(lm(x~y))

  summaries[counter] <- paste(capture.output(lm.model.sum), sep = '\n', collapse = '\n')
}


sink(file=paste(output_folder, "RegressionSummary_", counter,".txt", sep = ""))
summaries
sink()
```